# ImportError: Model A references Model B, Model B references Model A

Tags: python, django, circular-dependency

I think this is more a python question than Django.

But basically I'm doing at Model A:

```
from myproject.modelb.models import ModelB
```

and at Model B:

```
from myproject.modela.models import ModelA
```

Result:

> cannot import name ModelA

Am I doing something forbidden? Thanks

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/python-cyclic-imports

Comment: I couldn't find the answer to my problem, could I get some extra help please? Isn't what I'm doing possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Python module is imported by executing it top to bottom in a new namespace. When module A imports module B, the evaluation of A.py is paused until module B is loaded. When module B then imports module A, it gets the partly-initialized namespace of module A -- in your case, it lacks the `ModelA` class because the import of `myproject.modelb.models` happens before the definition of that class.

In Django you can fix this by referring to a model by name instead of by class object. So, instead of saying

```
from myproject.modela.models import ModelA
class ModelB:
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

you would use (without the import):

```
class ModelB:
    a = models.ForeignKey('ModelA')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas! Saved my day!
By the way, I think the syntax for `a = models.ForeignKey('ModelA')` is `models.ForeignKey('module.model')`, that's how it worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Mutual imports usually mean you've designed your models incorrectly.

When A depends on B, you should not have B also depending on A.

Break  B into two parts.

B1 - depends on A.

B2 - does not depend on A.

A depends on B1.  B1 depends on B2.  Circularity removed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! A person participates at max in one project, a project has only 1 leader. How do you remove the circularity from that?
Person references a project. Project references it's leader (person)

Comment: @Clash: Many-to-many relationships do not require both sides to explicitly reference the other.  You can do this in just one of the two.  And.  Why are they in separate modules?

Comment: S. Lott, it's not a many-to-many relationship, a person belongs to one project and a project has one leader

Comment: @Clash: Mutual relationships, like many-to-many, can be declared in just one place and will correctly reference the other.  You do not need both to mutually include each other.  **Why are they in separate modules?**

Comment: Oh, thank you S.Lott! That may be due because I missinterpreted the concept of modules... I thought project and person should be different modules, because they are different things

Comment: @Clash: Why did you think that?  Can you provide a quote or a reference?

Comment: There is no quote or reference... it's because on Django tutorial, poll is separate module from the user, so I thought project would be a separate module from the user too

Comment: "B1 depends on A, A depends on B1" - that still looks like a circular reference to me.

Comment: @Koterpillar: "A depends on B1. B1 depends on B2".  That's the change that's required.  You must make a change to eliminate the circularity.  The change involves decomposition of *at least* one module into two.  Sometimes both must be decomposed to eliminate the circularity.  With a vague question it's hard to be specific in the answer.